# override android MediaController's button

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, mediacontroller

I am in a situation where I have to go to next song when the user presses the seek forward button of mediacontroller and to previous song when the user presses the seek backward button. I know that I have to override the buttons of MediaControllers. But I am not sure how to do this? Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I suspect that you will be better off writing your own controller. It's not that hard. I did it in this ancient project: https://github.com/commonsguy/vidtry

Answer (score 1):

I think you can override the *MediaController.MediaPlayerControl*

```
abstract boolean     canPause()
abstract boolean     canSeekBackward()
abstract boolean     canSeekForward()
abstract int     getBufferPercentage()
abstract int     getCurrentPosition()
abstract int     getDuration()
abstract boolean     isPlaying()
abstract void    pause()
abstract void    seekTo(int pos)
abstract void    start()
```